# 2sls with interaction terms

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, 2sls

**I am running 2sls.**

Dependent variable - y

Independent variable - x

Instrumental variables - z1, z2, z3, z4

Interaction terms - x*z1, x*z2, x*z3, x*z4

Control variables

**Thus, the first stage of 2sls: x regressed on z1, z2, z3, z4, x*z1, x*z2, x*z3, x*z4.**

**Then the second stage: y regressed on predicted values of x, z1, z2, z3, z4, x*z1, x*z2, x*z3, x*z4, control variables.**

*Did I construct stages correctly or interaction terms should be included only in the second stage of 2sls?*